# Requests post on form not returning the generated page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'd like to scrape with python from this website: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/#ht=1

At the bottom, under the table of names, there are three tabs. I'm looking to POST to the form under the tab "Popular Names by Birth Year."

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/"

payload = {
    'year': 2010,
    'top': 50
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
# returns status 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

print soup.prettify()
```

This only returns the original page, not the generated page I'm looking for.

What could be the reason it's not returning the generated page?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the url for your `POST` request to http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi"
>>> payload = {
...     'year': 2010,
...     'top': 50
... }
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> table = soup.find('table', summary='Popularity for top 50')
>>> for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:4]:
...     print [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
... 
[u'1', u'Jacob', u'Isabella']
[u'2', u'Ethan', u'Sophia']
[u'3', u'Michael', u'Emma']
```